# Is there a way to compare XPaths to determine what type of element is being looked at?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium in Python3 and I'm working on a way to fill out a questionnaire. In this questionnaire I'm iterating through all of the questions and answering them. My problem is figuring out what type of question I'm dealing with, whether the question is multiple choice or a text question. What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
while questionsLeft:
    if currentQuestion == textQuestion:
        answerAsTextQuestion()
    elif currentQuestion == multChoice:
        answerAsMultChoice()
```

however I'm having trouble implementing this because I'm not sure how to verify if the element I'm looking at is a text box or a multiple choice question. Below is the HTML for a text question and a multiple choice question, respectively.

```
<div class="ng-scope" bo-if="questionResponse.question.type === 'TextQuestion'">

<div class="ng-scope" bo-if="questionResponse.question.type === 'SingleSelectQuestion' || questionResponse.question.type === 'PolarQuestion'">
```

What I have so far is the following, neither of the conditionals are passing so its going straight to the next section each time.

```
    self.set_filter("unanswered")

    all_sections = AssessmentSection(self.driver).get_all_section_names()
    print(all_sections)

        i = 1
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)

        for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[@bo-if])'):
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            print("in for loop at " + all_sections[j])
            if element.get_attribute("bo.if") == "questionResponse.question.type === 'TextQuestion'":
                print("found text question")
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//pre[@class="textareaClone"]//div').send_keys(XpathData.test_string)
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//pre[@class="textareaClone"]//div').send_keys(Keys.TAB)
                i += 1
            elif element.get_attribute(
                    "bo.if") == "questionResponse.question.type === 'SingleSelectQuestion' || questionResponse.question.type === 'PolarQuestion'":
                print("found choice question")
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    './/*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[' + str(
                        i) + ']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/label').click()
                i += 1


        Wait(self.driver, Wait.timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), \'' + all_sections[j] + '\')]')))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), \'' + all_sections[j] + '\')]').click()
        j += 1
        print(j)
```

Comment: can you share `HTML` sample for both elements? Also share code for `questionsLeftInQuestionnaire()`

Comment: Added the HTML for the elements. As of now questionsLeftInQuestionnaire() has a loop that iterates through all of the questions and throws an exception when the iterator doesn't have any remaining questions left to reference.

Answer (score 1):

As your `questionsLeftInQuestionnaire()` logic is hidden, below is simplified version of code you might implement:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@bo-if]'):
    if element.get_attribute("bo.if") == "questionResponse.question.type === 'TextQuestion'":
        answerAsTextQuestion()
    elif element.get_attribute("bo.if") == "questionResponse.question.type === 'SingleSelectQuestion' || questionResponse.question.type === 'PolarQuestion'":
        answerAsMultChoice()
```

If values of attribute `bo-if` are different for each element, you can try to use `if "||" in element.get_attribute("bo.if")` condition

Comment: I added my full code, I believe I'm having a problem with the conditionals not resolving either of the question types(multChoice and Text)

Comment: What is the output of your code? Which lines seem to be cause of your issue? Can you share page `URL` or it is confidential?

Comment: With what I have now the code has no errors. Based on the logic the code runs through each section thinking that there are no more questions to answer. That is to say that it starts on section 1, sees no questions left to answer (which is wrong), and goes to the next section and continues until the last section. I'm afraid the `URL` is confidential, my apologies.

Comment: You get no errors because all lines are in `try`/`except` block and you didn't specify exact exceptions you want to catch... That's not the best approach... Could you try to remove `try`/`except` and share exception log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9bcXbVsJ Here's the error log, the reason it is crashing in this case is because it thinks its at the end of the sections and is going out of range, which is normally caught by the `try/except` parts.

Comment: Share `HTML` of element you want to match with `'//div[contains(text(), \'' + all_sections[j] + '\')]'`

Comment: `<div class="section_sectionNamePlacement ng-binding">Experience and Track Record</div>` this is the `HTML` of one of the many sections, if you want the parent `HTML` I can get you that too.

Comment: `all_sections` is a list, right? Question 1: is there something wrong with indentation on provided code? :) Could you edit your code to make it more clear? Question 2:  why you set initial value of `j` to `1`? Indexation starts from `0`. In your code you just ignore the first element of list

Comment: You are correct that j should start at 0, I have fixed that now :). I don't see anything wrong with the indentation of the code, but I'll put some time into it to try to make the code clearer.

Comment: After looking into it more the problem seems to be that the conditionals are never resolving. I'll update my original question with the new code, keep at it, and come back if I discover something.